# cant' get camel route to JMs active mq working

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

First user of camel/JMS/acivemq.

I set up a jms camel route and I'm trying to send as test text and see it in the active mq GUI http://127.0.0.1:8161/admin/topics.jsp but I am not seeing anything. This is my first time trying to get this all to work and really need to see something in active mq to prove that this is working correctly.

Here is the camel route

```
     <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="com.srcinc.ogre.alerts">
    <cm:default-properties>
      <cm:property name="jmsHostName" value="localhost" />
      <cm:property name="jmsPort" value="61616" />
      <cm:property name="jmsUserName" value="system" />
      <cm:property name="jmsPassword" value="manager" />
    </cm:default-properties>
  </cm:property-placeholder>
  <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://${jmsHostName}:${jmsPort}" />
    <property name="userName" value="${jmsUserName}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jmsPassword}" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="pooledJmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledJmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
  </bean>
  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="AlertProcessorJMSDistributionRoute">
      <from uri="vm:send-jms-alert?multipleConsumers=true" />
      <to uri="activemq:topic:Alerts" />
    </route>
  </camelContext>
```

Here is my Java code that references the appropriate camel route.

```
   private static final String VM__JMS_ROUTE = "vm::send-jms-alert";
    private ProducerTemplate mProducer;
    mProducer  = new DefaultCamelContext().createProducerTemplate();
    mProducer.sendBody(VM__JMS_ROUTE, "Testing 123");
```

Comment: There's no need for that many exclamation marks, instead elaborate on your question.

Comment: before I always had to worry about not making making questions too long so I was always trying to keep my questions not too wordy. I have never run into this issue of having too much code. Any ideas anybody? I am able to see ActiveMQAdvisory.Connection  messages enqueued in Active MQ but I not see my queue or topic

Answer (score 0):

In your Java code you should only have one colon, `vm:send-jms-alert` instead of `vm::send-jms-alert`